# Auto-login doesn't work for per-site-metas

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, login, per-site-meta

When I go to a per-site meta without visiting the  parent site (and thus being auto-logged-in there), I am not automatically logged-in. Would it be possible to do this?

This could be useful if you were linked to a meta topic from MSO and want to comment, and thus haven't gone through the parent site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meta account essentially *is* your parent account.  This is one of the reasons the `login` link goes to the parent site.

Additionally, you should be visiting the parent site much more frequently than the meta site.  A little login impedance helps that along.